# Use bokeh components with elementtree

Tags: python, elementtree, bokeh

I'm using bokeh's [component](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) to get `script` and `div` tags for embedding graphs in an html report.  The report is built with [elementtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#).

The issue is that `component` returns `script` and `div` as strings, meaning I can't conveniently use `SubElement` to make the appropriate elements.  These strings work fine if you're writing directly to a file, but I'm stuck using etree to parse the string and determine the properties.  It feels clunky.

Has anyone else run into this?  It would be great if there was a way to get component to return two dictionaries, something like this:

```
script = {
    tag='script',
    type='text/javascript',
    data=#script contents here
}

id= {
    tag='div',
    class='bk-root',
    id='6c76dbfe-52ec-4388-b408-a3142466196e'
}
```

Comment: Is your main question "how to get the id?" just asking, because the rest would be static code... (apart from the data)

Comment: @renzop Yes, I suppose it's just the data I need from the script and the id I need from the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to check the [reference documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.components), `components` already has keyword argument flags for providing the information as raw data and not HTML tags:

```
wrap_script (boolean, optional) :
    If True, the returned javascript is wrapped in a script tag.
    (default: True)

wrap_plot_info (boolean, optional) : If True, returns ``<div>`` strings.
    Otherwise, return dicts that can be used to build your own divs.
    (default: True)

    If False, the returned dictionary contains the following information:

    {
        'modelid':  'The model ID, used with Document.get_model_by_id',
        'elementid': 'The css identifier the BokehJS will look for to target the plot',
        'docid': 'Used by Bokeh to find the doc embedded in the returned script',
    }
```